# What are the differences between free, dealloc, release, and autorelease?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

Can someone explain the differences between `free()`, `release`, `autorelease` and `dealloc`?

Answer (score 21):

`free()` is a C function that you use to dispose of no longer needed memory you obtained through `malloc()` or other function that is documented to require free() to deallocate its memory e.g. `strdup()`.

`-dealloc` is an Objective-C selector that is sent by the Objective-C runtime to an object when the object is no longer owned by any part of the application.

`-release` is the selector you send to an object to indicate that you are relinquishing ownership of that object.  Once an object is not owned by anybody, it is sent the `-dealloc` message by the runtime.

`-autorelease` is a selector you send to an object to indicate you are relinquishing ownership of the object.  However if nobody now owns the object the final `-dealloc` will be deferred until some unspecified later point.  In fact, what you are really doing is transferring your ownership to an autorelease pool which will then release it when it is itself released (or drained).

You must never send `-dealloc` to an object except to `super` in the object's own `-dealloc` method.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the 4 methods you've mentioned you'll typically only use `release` and `autorelease` in objective-c. `free` maybe used when you've used c and `malloc` otherwise you should use `release` and `autorelease`.

`dealloc` shouldn't be called by any of your code as it can interfere with the retain/release cycle that objective-c uses to keep track of resources. Using `dealloc` will almost certainly result in crashes at runtime if you ever use it.

The ultimate resource of the use of the `release` and `autorelease` is the [Apple memory management  documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

Answer (score 3):

- `free` is the opposite of `malloc` and is used in C. You'll likely not use it very much programming in Objective C
- If you own an object, you `release` it when you're done with it
- You can also `autorelease` an object. This automatically releases it at the end of the current run loop iteration
- When the reference count on an object drops to zero, the runtime calls `dealloc`. You should not call this method yourself

You "own" an object if you `alloc`, `new`, `retain` or `copy` it.

Apple provide [some good documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) on this.

Comment: Point 3: I'd call it "run-loop iteration" instead of "run-loop".
Point 4: Certainly, you meant to say "dealloc" instead of "release", don't you? (sorry, nitpicking)

Comment: Thanks very much. That was definitely helpful.

Comment: I think you need to read the document you linked to more carefully.  You do not own an object you `init`, you own an object you create with `new`, `alloc` or a method containing the word `copy`.  You also own an object you retain.

Comment: Also, an autoreleased object may not last until the end of the runloop iteration.  It will only last until the autorelease pool is drained.  *Normally* that would be at the end of the runloop iteration, but you are allowed to create new autorelease pools too.

Comment: @Stephen you do **not** own an object if you init or retain it you own it if you new, alloc, retain, or copy it.

Comment: Actually I was aiming to keep it simple/clear, albeit with a slight loss in accuracy. Apparently that failed so I've corrected my answer.