# Difference between free() and release

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between free, dealloc, release, and autorelease?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335350/what-are-the-differences-between-free-dealloc-release-and-autorelease)

I want to get rid of my allocated memory used in my app. I know I need to use `release` but what is the difference between `free()` and `release`? Are they the same?

Comment: Don't even bother with `release`; use ARC and `retain/release` goes away.  You should only use `free` when you have manually called `malloc` in your code.  I think you need to read up on Objective C if you are getting confused.

Comment: Use ARC. Use ARC. Use ARC. that is all

Comment: arc is just not sufficent, it will only release objects only when it needs to be released instead of immediately releasing it and thus creating cluster of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`free()` is part of the C standard library, so it's a function. It immediately frees the allocated memory obtained using `malloc()`, so it must be passed a pointer that is allocated by `malloc()`, else it invokes undefined behavior.

`- release` is a **method** (as opposed to a function) of the `NSObject` class. It does not immediately free memory; it only decrements an object's reference count by one. It then also checks for it being 0 - if it is zero, it invokes `- dealloc` (which is usually overridden by a subclass to free memory allocated by the constructor method, `- init` or `free()` memory allocated by `malloc()`).

So they are not the same at all, ***do not even attempt to use them interchangeably!***

Comment: I thought an `NSObject` was allocated by its `+ alloc` method...

Comment: @MikeDeSimone The object itself is allocated by `+ alloc`, then in `init`, additional objects may be created or otherwise memory may be allocated in a subclass.

Comment: so if i have something like this:NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:exportPath]; should i release like [release videoData] it or free(videoData) ?

Comment: @arunjalota after having read the answer, it should be obvious. If it isn't, please read a comprehendsive Objective-C tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

The more interesting part is how free works: (and in this direction, malloc too can be understood better)

In many malloc/free implementations, free does normally not return the memory to the operating system (or at least only in rare cases). The reason is, that you will get gaps in your heap and thus it can happen, that you just finish of your 2 or 4 GB of virtual memory with gaps. This should be avoided of course, since as soon as the virtual memory is finished, you will be in really big trouble. The other reason of course is, that the OS can only handle memory chunks that are of a specific size and alignment. To be specific: Normally the OS can only handle blocks that the virtual memory manager can handle (most often multiples of 512 Bytes eg. 4KB).

So returning 40 Bytes to the OS will just not work. So what does free do?

Free will put the memory block in its own free block list. Normally it also tries to meld together adjacent blocks in the address space. The free block list is just a circular list of memory chunks which have of course some admin data in the beginning. This is also the reason, why managing very small memory elements with the standard malloc/free is not efficient. Every memory chunk needs additional data and with smaller sizes more fragmentation happens.

The free-list is also the first location, malloc looks for a new chunk of memory when needed. It is scanned before it calls for new memory from the OS. When a chunk is found that is bigger then the needed memory, it is just divided into two parts. One is returned to caller, the other is put back into the free list.

**Release**:Cocoa uses certain naming conventions. Anything that starts with alloc, new, or copy returns something with a retainCount of 1 and you are required to release.When release is called the reatinCount decrements by 1

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer the question.